# String read from a file is not getting parsed to localdate

Tags: java, netbeans

```
public class Loan {

 private Borrower Borrower;
 private Book Book;
 private LocalDate issueDate;
 private LocalDate returnDate;
 private int status;

 public Loan(Borrower Borrower, Book Book, LocalDate issueDate, LocalDate returnDate, int status) {
    this.Borrower = Borrower;
    this.Book = Book;
    this.issueDate = issueDate;
    this.returnDate = returnDate;
    this.status = status;
 }

 public LocalDate getIssueDate() {
    return issueDate;
 }

 public void setIssueDate(LocalDate issueDate) {
    this.issueDate = issueDate;
 }

 public LocalDate getReturnDate() {
    return returnDate;
 }

 public void setReturnDate(LocalDate returnDate) {
    this.returnDate = returnDate;
 }

 public int getStatus() {
    return status;
 }

 public void setStatus(int status) {
    this.status = status;
 }

 public Borrower getBorrower() {
    return Borrower;
 }

 public void setBorrower(Borrower Borrower) {
    this.Borrower = Borrower;
 }

 public Book getBook() {
    return Book;
 }

 public void setBook(Book Book) {
    this.Book = Book;
 }

}    

ArrayList<Loan> Loans= new ArrayList();

try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\NimraArif\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\ooad1\\src\\ooad1\\Loans.txt"));
    String line = null;

    int bookid, status, borrowerid;

    line = reader.readLine();

    while (line!= null) {

      String[] values = line.split(",");

      bookid = Integer.valueOf(values[0]);
      borrowerid=Integer.valueOf(values[1]);
      DateTimeFormatter formatter= DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yy");
      LocalDate issueDate=LocalDate.parse(values[2],formatter);
      LocalDate returnDate=LocalDate.parse(values[3],formatter);
      status=Integer.valueOf(values[4]);
      Book temp = null; 
      Borrower temp2 = null;

      for (int i = 0; i < Books.size(); i++) {
        if (Books.get(i).getBookid()==bookid) {
          temp=Books.get(i);
        }
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < borrowers.size(); i++) {
        if (borrowers.get(i).getRollno()==borrowerid) {
          temp2=borrowers.get(i);
        }
      }

      Loan temp3 = new Loan(temp2, temp, issueDate, returnDate, status);
      Loans.add(temp3);
      line = reader.readLine();
    }
    reader.close();

  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.format("Exception occurred trying to read '%s'.", "Loans.txt");
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

When I execute this code, it throws an exception at the line while contains the parse function. However, if I hard code the string myself, it works fine. I can't understand why this is happening.

This is the output obtained from `e.printStackTrace();`:

```
'Loans.txt'.java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2017/11/01' could not be parsed at index 2
        at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
        at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
        at java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:400)
        at ooad1.Ooad1.main(Ooad1.java:119)
Exception occurred trying to read 'Holder.txt'.
```

Comment: Can you update you question with exception print stack track

Comment: Always log or print the stack trace of caught exception which is not chained to another exception.  In your case, your `catch` block needs to contain `e.printStackTrace();`.  Once you’ve done that, edit your question and add the full stack trace to it.

Comment: Have you visually inspected the data in loans.txt?  Perhaps there's an invalid date in the file?

Comment: I have updated the question and copied the output after putting e.printStackTrace(); @SamDev

Comment: @BillHileman i have copied my class loan here too. I am using localdate in it.

Answer (score 1):

> String read from a file is not getting parsed to localdate

LocalDate is an immutable class that represents Date with default format of yyyy-MM-dd. We can use now() method to get the current date. We can also provide input arguments for year, month and date to create LocalDate instance.

Use a formatter to parse single character day/month fields for `java.time.LocalDate`

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");
LocalDate ldate = LocalDate.parse("2017/11/01", formatter);
```

Then you can use `LocalDate` for your `setter` method, You'll get no exception after.

***For example***

```
setIssueDate(ldate);
setReturnDate(ldate);
```